# How to run 2008R2 SSIS packages on SQL Server 2014 Standard environment?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In current, I have a .NET application which is executing 2008R2 SSIS packages and the application are running on win server 2008r2 (64bit). These packages were built in BIDS 2008. After that, I upgraded my database server from SQL2008R2 to SQL2014 Standard (running on Win server 2012R2) and deployed .NET app to new environment.

An now, I'm encountering the issues with calling package from .NET application. The message error is ERROR: Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public Key=..." or one of it's dependencies. An attempt was made to load program with an incorrect format.

Step 1: create a .NET simple app to call package (SSIS 2008). I also add 2 .dll version (10.0.0.0) for reference
Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap and Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS allocated in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

using Application = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application;


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

try
{

string pkgLocation = @".\Package.dtsx";

Application app = new Application();

Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

DTSExecResult pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

MessageBox.Show(pkgResults.ToString());

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
}
}
```

Step 2: deploy this app (included 2 .dll, the package) to new environment and execute it. The result is error message as above.

In new environment, 2 .dll is version 12.0.2000.8 allocate in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies. And I guess that whenever the package is executed it also requires some functions of old .dll version 10.0.0.0 to execute their's components (Execute SQL Task, Task Script,...) but these .dll is not existed in new environment and it causes error.

So, how can I resolve the issue except upgrading SSIS packages to 2014 or any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Comment: These links might help .. [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f3e67634-ef0a-4c97-9473-31e0ca1f6814/ssis-2012-assembly-reference-error) and [link2](http://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/using-ssis-2008-components-in-sql-server-data-tools-with-ssis-2012/)

Answer (score 1):

Your 2008R2 packages need to be upgraded to 2014 since you did an upgrade of the server, rather than a side-by-side install.  So there are two possibilities that I can think of:

1. Upgrade all the packages to 2014, this might be as simple as opening
   them up in SSDT-BI 2014 and saving them (not in the project model
   but as stand alone packages).  It is doubtful that any code would be
   broken from R2 to 2014, there were many enhancements as opposed to fundamental changes.
2. Or install SSIS 2008R2 on your server again
   and have your .NET application call DTEXEC from the correct folder. 
   i.e. on my machine it is in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
   Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe.  You can also change the path
   variable to make sure that the 2008 dtexec is on top of the 2014.

Comment: In my case, .Net application is executing the packages by C# code, not use DTEXEC. I doubt that whenever my package are executed, some components are required old version (10.0.0.0).

Comment: Installing the 2008r2 version of ssis should still resolve your reference issues. When you upgraded, you replaced those assemblies.

Comment: How's about license if I install 2008r2 SSIS on new server (2014 Standard)

Comment: I'm not sure.  You're license should allow you to have multiple instances on the same server with no additional cost.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I found out the solution to resolve this by modifying configuration file of .NET application. I was in terrible time. Thanks for your support again.

Comment: I'm facing the new issue of Task Script component. This step detects Text Qualifier property and then set value to variable @[User:TextQualifier]. After that, I configure Text Qualifier of Flat File within this variable. The process run successfully in 2008 but there is an error in 2014, it does not understand variable @[User:TextQualifier].

Comment: That should be @[User::TextQualifier] with two colons. And I think you need to start some new threads here :)